# How should I handle different transitions to the same state in redux? E.g. I want a state change to be animated, but only sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reswift

#### Background

I’m an iOS dev, but I want to tap the expertise of redux experts on any platform - I started using ReSwift to use redux and I am having difficulty finding a solution to a problem that would seem to be quite common.

#### Problem

I have a situation where I have a bunch of cities in a list stored in state.  When the user drags to reposition a city, we dispatch a reorder action which adjusts the state properly.

However, we need the UI to know the from and to positions for reordering.  So right now we stash the most recent reorder action's from/to position in state too.
That seems like an antipattern for redux - is there a better way?

#### Fundamental queston

How should you best communicate information to views/subscribers about *how* a state change should be performed, when there are multiple ways that could result in the same state?

#### Simpler Example

A simpler example is if you want to show a change animated in some circumstances, non-animated in others.
You might want to support a `shouldAnimate` parameter in an action, but that is not actually state, it’s about you transitioned to a state.

I could solve the problem by keeping a `lastStateChangeIsAnimated` in state - or even just the last action itself - but that seems like I am working around redux.

Thanks for your help!!